# What is the difference between declaring a variable within and outside a function?

Tags: javascript

```
//I have written the below code in JS.

var output = [];
var num =1 ;
function fizzBuzz(){
    var a = output.push(num);
    num ++;
    console.log(output);
}
```

// Each time I call the function the values are incremented by 1. So the output is:

```
fizzBuzz();
[1]
fizzBuzz();
[1,2]
fizzBuzz();
[1,2,3]
```

//  And so on:

//  However when I write the code like this:

```
var output = [];
function fizzBuzz(){
    var num =1 ;
    var a = output.push(num);
    num ++;
    console.log(output);
}
```

// The output is different.

```
fizzBuzz();
[1]
fizzBuzz();
[1,1]
fizzBuzz();
[1,1,1]
```

// and so on.

//  May I know the logic behind this?

Comment: If you declare the variable inside the function, then every time the function is called, you create a new variable. And you're initializing that variable to 1. If you declare it outside, then it's created only once.

Comment: [What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: Please do look the documentation on function scope, block scope and global scope in javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be a variable scope topic, and it is best to check out "variable scope" and "global scope".

In your first example, this is considered a "global variable scope."

```
var output = []; // output variable declared in global scope.
var num =1 ; // num variable declared in global scope.
function fizzBuzz(){
  var a = output.push(num); // a variable declared in function scope.
  num ++;
  console.log(output);
}
```

`output` and the `num` are available and their respective values are still stored every time you call `fizzBuzz`. That is why you are getting `[1, 2, 3]` as values.

the second example can be considered as a function scope. Every time you call `fizzBuzz`, you are always creating a new `num` variable and setting it to 1. Hence the result `[1, 1, 1]`

See more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Scope